# How to solve this convex QP?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $\bf \Sigma$ and a real-valued vector $\bf r$,

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {{\bf w}} {\text{minimize}} & {\bf w}^\top {\bf \Sigma} \, {\bf w} \\ \text{subject to} & {\bf 1}^\top {\bf w} = 1 \\ & {\bf r}^\top {\bf w} \geq r_0 \\ & {\bf w} \geq {\bf 0} \end{array} $$

I know how to solve equality-constrained quadratic programs, but I am not sure how to solve inequality-constrained quadratic programs.  Should I introduce a slack variable?

Comment: Do you need to solve this QP analytically? Solving it numerically should be easy

Comment: My first preference was an analytical solution, but seems like a tough one to solve. A numeric solution is fine. Can you please give me some directions?

Comment: I like working with Python.

Comment: Then you might want to try [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/quadratic_program.html)

Comment: Sure, thanks! Appreciate it.

Comment: Hint : visualize the situation in the 3D case ; you have a family of homothetical ellipsoids with the origin as their common center. You keep only the "chunks" of these ellipsoids which are "above" plane $ax+by+cz=r_0$ and  then take the intersection with the plane $x+y+z=1$, giving arc of ellipses... or void sets... all this being restricted to the first octant.

Comment: @JeanMarie - thanks for such a nice explanation.